# How to implement some if-then logic with JSF and Facelets?

Tags: java, jsf, jstl, facelets

I have a bean with field `status`. Depending on `status` value different css class should be applied to render it.

So, I need something like this (very far from real things pseudocode):

```
if status == "Approved"
     cssClass = "green"
if status == "Rejected"
     cssClass = "red"
<span class="cssClass">Some info</span>
```

I tried to apply `jstl` but I can't make it work with facelets and jsf (but I heard that it is possible, maybe its truth). Here is the code:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{report.approved}">
        <c:set var="statusClass" value="approved"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="#{report.rejected}">
        <c:set var="statusClass" value="rejected"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="#{report.inProgress}">
        <c:set var="statusClass" value="progress"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="#{report.pendingHR}">
        <c:set var="statusClass" value="pending"/>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
<span class="status ${statusClass}">#{report.formattedStatus}</span>
```

How should it be done with JSF/Facelets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To give the both sides (model and view) the benefit, rather make use of an `enum` instead of four independent booleans which might after all only lead to maintenance trouble.

```
public enum Status {
    APPROVED, REJECTED, PROGRESS, PENDING;
}
```

It is not only much easier and cleaner to handle in Java side, but you can also just print it in EL.

```
<span class="#{bean.status}" />
```

Comment: Without checking, wouldn't the toString() still be uppercased?

Comment: Yes, it will. It shouldn't be that much work to update CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The JSF approach is typically using the `rendered` attribute on the h-tags. Also note that the EL (expression language) is quite expressive in JSF so you can use `?:` in your class expression. E.g.

```
<span class="status #{report.approved ? 'approved' : report.rejected ? 'rejected' : report.inProgress ? 'progress' : report.pendingHR ? 'pending' : ''}">
```

Comment: Whee, StackOverflow automagically converts hints into code :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make `cssStatus` a properties in the backing bean that is resolved to the correct CSS class.

```
public String getCssStatus() {
    if( this.status == .... )
       return "green";
    else 
       ...
}
```

And then

```
<span class="status #{report.cssStatus}">#{report.formattedStatus}</span>
```

AFAIK, this should work.

Comment: I thought about it but I still hope that there is a better solution exist. I wouldn't like to tie css classes names with java code in beans.

Comment: @Roman I don't see anything wrong with this approach. You don't want to tie class name with their actual rendering, which is the point of CSS, but having presentation logic decide the class to render seems fine to me. No matter what, there will be some presentation logic somewhere which will pick the CSS class based on the report's status. As long as this presentation logic is in the presentation layer, it's ok.

Comment: I can imagine that one don't want to clutter the model with view specifics.